# Eth0 Has two IP addresses

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, networkmanager, dhcpcd, pi-hole

I have a Pihole with a fixed IP, 192.168.0.3. It works, and I can get to the GUI interface with that IP.

Recently I noticed my router displaying alternating IP addresses for the Pi in its UI (the router lists clients by Mac).

I tried navigating to the second address on the same subnet and the Pihole GUI is served.

`ip a` shows a bunch of stuff but here is eth0...

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:eb:de:54:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.64/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 86015sec preferred_lft 86015sec
    inet 192.168.0.3/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf` shows...

```
interface eth0
        static ip_address=192.168.0.3/24
        static routers=192.168.0.1
        static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

Other notes...

- WiFi is disabled on the Pi
- I only have one DHCP server on the network
- The Pi DHCP server is disabled
- I have a docker container on the Pi serving HAAS
- I have a backup Pihole on the network fixed to 192.168.0.2, which doesn't have this issue

Comment: So you ask where 192.168.0.64 comes from? Have you checked the logs? System log, or NetworkManager log, or systemd-networkd log, or whatever is adequate.

Comment: "cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf shows..." : so you're asking your DHCP *client* to add a static IP (.3) *in addition* to its main role: ask an IP to the DHCP server. All is working as configured. Don't use a DHCP client if you don't want a dynamic IP (or else configure the DHCP *server* to provide a reserved IP).

Comment: Standard method when this isn't immediately seen: compare the two Pi's network configurations and figure out what is the difference in their configuration.

Comment: @A.B I compared `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` on both Piholes and they are the same. One is set to .3 and the other .2 as configured during the Pihole auto setup script.

Comment: Ok. Then remove dhcp client settings on both anyway. Problem solved

Comment: What might be simple for you obviously isn't simple for me. The issue is something in the OS seems to be requesting an address. Why? How do I find it and stop it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the bootstrap Pihole setup does all this. Nothing in dhcp.conf seems to suggest eth0 should be looking for an address since it's already configured as static. What else might be looking for and setting an address?

Comment: Ok reading [dhcpcd.conf](https://manpages.debian.org/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.conf.5) 's doc  (don't confuse the word: dhcpcd.conf: it's a client), with the `static` keyword there shouldn't be any lease asked by dhcpcd which should play the role of a simple address configurator then. So I don't know why such lease was still asked.

Comment: @A.B Finally fixed this. So posted an answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some help over [here](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/help-pi-hole-has-two-ip-addresses/48175)

NetworkManager was taking over. I probably installed it at some point for one of it's tools, never intending it to actively take over my Pi as a DHCP client. Honestly, I'm surprised this doesn't happen more often. It was quite tricky to troubleshoot.           I have WiFi disabled on my Pi, and in investigating I couldn't enable WiFi either. NM is a handful!

I also somehow disabled DHCPD when troubleshooting, so initially disabling NM simply took the Pi offline and I have to connect a monitor/keyboard since SSH went down. In the end here is what fixed it...

`sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd`

followed by...

`sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager`